# Возврат прежней точки карты в Google maps api

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Имеется две активности: первая -карта, вторая - просто пустая активность. Сценарий такой: покрутили, попередвигали карту (первая активность), нажали кнопку - перешли во вторую активность. Далее нажимаем на крестик во второй активности, который Intent'ом возвращает нас в первую активность к карте. Но хотелось бы возвращаться в ту же точку на карте и с тем же zoom'ом. Как это правильно реализовать? Посредством чего?

Возвратить ту же самую точку проблем нет. Но как сохранить zoom карты и при  возврате на карту восстановить значения zoom'а?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 варианта:

1. Возвращаться на 1 активити не интенетом, но закрытием 2 активити через `Activity#finish()` - так состояние должно само восстановиться.
2. Запускать 1 активити интентом, но с флагом `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` или `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` - запустится уже запущенный ранее экземпляр с восстановленным состоянием
3. Запускать интентом, но прописать в манифесте что активити всегда только одна, т.е. запустится уже запущенный ранее экземпляр с восстановленным состоянием:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
         android:launchMode="singleTask"
         android:label="@string/app_name" />
   ```
4. Сохранить в префы зум, полученный так (с установлением его в `onCreate` первой активити):

   ```
   float zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
   ```